# Пользуетесь ли вы интструментами для code review?

Tags: инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Интересует вопрос, пользуется ли кто-нибудь интструментами для ревью в рамках командной работы? Какими? и почему именно ими? каким образом происходит ревью в вашей компании?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас в компании используется [Atlassian Crucible](https://ru.atlassian.com/software/crucible), Почему он? - Потому что на момент покупки он был поинтереснее чем [JetBrains Upsource](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/) по количеству фич(самая главная была это просмотр репозитория с возможностью навигации по коду), тогда он был версии 1.0, Сейчас уже, наверное, купили бы второй.

До `Crucible` мы просто смотрели код через ide и использовали внутреннюю почту, для обмена сообщениями.